# home.arpa vs subdomain.home.arpa domain name in my home network

Tags: networking, home-networking, domain-name

I am planning to give a domain name to a computer on my home network. From my understanding, `home.arpa` has been officially reserved since 2018 for this use case ([RFC 8375](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8375)). Does this mean that I can assign `home.arpa` itself as a domain name for one of my computers, or does it have to be a subdomain of `home.arpa` (e.g. `mycomputer.home.arpa`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuring "home.arpa" as a zone in your DNS server and putting A/AAAA records directly at the zone root works exactly the same way as doing it with public DNS domains: it really doesn't matter whether you do it. It's the same as "superuser.com" having A/AAAA records at the zone root.

Specifying "home.arpa" as the domain name in OS will already result in "mycomputer.home.arpa" being the computer's FQDN. The domain parameter doesn't replace the machine's name, it acts as a suffix.

Configuring a computer with "home.arpa" as its *hostname* (FQDN) will make it assume `arpa` as the actual domain, which will be weird and generally not what you want. (For example, it will start to expand unqualified names to "whatever.arpa" instead of "whatever.home.arpa", and while home.arpa has been specifically set up to allow your internal DNS to intercept it, the rest of the arpa domain has *not* been set up that way – and would break rDNS if you did, due to it being under "in-addr.arpa" – so you'll end up with spamming IANA's DNS servers with queries for all your internal hostnames.)